# Thread safe SQLAlchemy session for Pyramid requests

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, thread-safety, pyramid

The article **[What the Zope Transaction Manager Means To Me (and you)](https://metaclassical.com/what-the-zope-transaction-manager-means-to-me-and-you/)**, demonstrates a nice way to attach an SQLAlchemy DB session to each request this way:

```
def includeme(config):
    settings = config.get_settings()
    engine = engine_from_config(settings)

    maker = sessionmaker()
    register(maker)
    maker.configure(bind=engine)

    config.add_request_method(lambda request: maker(), 'db_session', reify=True)
```

The problem with this approach is that "the transaction manager is still provided as a threadlocal under this design". Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: It is not just transaction management; here you also have thread-local constraints on sessions.  Have you looked at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/mmerickel/84b34ee5d68ed20dae10#file-model-py-L16-L19
Thanks to some improvements in the `pyramid_tm` package you can actually completely remove the threadlocal transaction manager. Whether that is a good idea or not is up to you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Whether that is a good idea or not is up to you" Are there any circumstances where one would want to not avoid thread-locals?

Comment: There may be certain packages that expect the threadlocals to be available as it's the default method of interacting with the `transaction` package (the underlying package that `zope.sqlalchemy`, `pyramid_tm`, etc are using to coordinate commits).